# C# Update SQL Server table based on results from a select statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, dictionary, sql-update

**Background**

I'm trying to update a specific set of rows returned from a select statement in a table. The table consists of an id and value. The ids are not unique because there is a column indicating a revision.

**Currently**

What I'm looking to do is update the values for the *most recent* revision per id from within C#.

So far, the select statement I have written returns all the ids and values for the most recent revision.

```
SELECT id, value
FROM table1 AS T1
WHERE createdOn = (SELECT MAX(createdOn)
                   FROM table1 AS T2
                   WHERE T1.id = T2.id)
```

I have created SQL parameters in C# which contain the id and the value. I will use the id to identify which row I need to insert the new value for. I will of course use the value as the value to be inserted at that id.

Here are the parameters:

```
SqlParameter idParameter = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
SqlParameter valueParameter = new SqlParameter("@updatedValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
```

Within C# I have a dictionary used to store the ids and values that have already been updated to their new values in the code before.

```
Dictionary<int, string> updatedValues = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

I intend to loop through this dictionary and set the SQL parameters to that of the current key and value in the dictionary. The code I currently have looks like this:

```
foreach (var entry in updatedValues)
{
    idParameter.Value = entry.Key;
    valueParameter.Value = entry.Value;

    //perform sql update command
}
```

As indicated by the comment I believe it is here that the SQL update command needs to be executed.

Guidance as to how to do this and what the SQL query string would look like to make sure that only the *most recent* revision is updated would be much appreciated.

**Things I've tried**

I've tried modifying my SQL query to use joins to then hopefully be easier to modify into an update command, with no luck. I have also attempted to insert the results from my query into a temporary table and then try to perform the update on the temporary table. However I then reach another problem when trying to get the temporary table into the actual table.

Thanks in advance

Side note: I have modified variable names in order to try and allow others to adapt to their code easier if a solution works for them well too

Comment: I am confused, admittedly it doesn't take much...Your SQL query gets the latest ID and Value based on the created date, you then load it into the dictionary and want to loop through the dictionary to update the latest revision? But, are you not just updating the latest with the latest you have just got? Or is this update going into a different table?

Comment: Yes, I want to loop through the dictionary to execute the update command for each id where the value has been updated in the C# code before. The computation has already been done on the new value to be inserted. I have got the data, modified it and now I'm looking to put that new data back into the database. Hope this clears it up a little!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your select statement:

```
SELECT id, value
FROM table1 AS T1
WHERE createdOn = 
    (SELECT MAX(createdOn)
        FROM table1 AS T2
        WHERE T1.id = T2.id)
```

And the corresponding update statement would be:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.value = 'your value'
FROM table1 AS T1
WHERE createdOn = 
    (SELECT MAX(createdOn)
        FROM table1 AS T2
        WHERE T1.id = T2.id)
```

Comment: This is great thanks! Is there a chance where the results would be retrieved in a different order? Would I need to specify the id from my SQL parameter and use it in the update statement too? Like id = @id

Comment: I have slightly modified the update statement to included id = '@id' just to be on the safe side but thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just retrieve createdOn in your original select statement and then use that, along with id, to identify the exact row, e.g.

UPDATE table1 SET value = @updatedValue WHERE id = @id and createdOn = @createdOn

Comment: Are you saying that I need to somehow store createdOn in my C# code to then use it in an update statement as a parameter?

Comment: yes, that's what I was suggesting. Have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: No you haven't, I feel like it could be a solution however I would need to modify my dictionary to allow me to store 3 values. Do you think using the id as a key and then creating a Pair<string, date> as the value would work?

Comment: @GeorgeFeakes I was just writing out an answer, but this is pretty much it. Use a tuple to store it all in, have the ID, VALUE and CREATEDON in there, then create a stored proc, and pass to it the 3 values, to perform what spodger has suggested.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't really explain it all but @Leonidas199x has added the missing bit.

Comment: Thanks guys! I feel like I could get it to work this way. Just open to maybe slightly more efficient methods at the moment still as the SQL seems very long compared to the partition method I have seen now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use partition by, try `select distinct id,max(createdOn) over (partition by id) as "lastcreatedOn" from YourTable`
This will partition your table by each id and select the maximum date value per id. Put this into a stored procedure an pass your id and new value inside to load that kind of work to the db server an not your c# code, I'd suggest.
EDIT: maybe like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateWhatever   
    <@id> nvarchar(255),  
    <@value> nvarchar(255)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    select distinct id,@LastRev = max(createdOn) over (partition by id) as "lastcreatedOn"  
from YourTable  
where id=@id

update YourTable set value = @val  
where id=@id and createdOn=@LastRev
END
```

Comment: I really like this SQL code however I'm not sure what you mean by 'putting it into a stored procedure' - could you clarify please?